# Symfony 4.2 Creating Repository as service in vendor/acme/demo-bundle

Tags: service, doctrine, repository, symfony4

I am working on a third party bundle which is in the vendor/ directory.

I have an Entity class which looks like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\DemoBundle\Repository\ArticleRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="acme_demo_article")
 */
class Article
```

And a Repository class like this:

```
class ArticleRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(RegistryInterface $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, Article::class);
    }
}
```

This generates the following error:

> The "Acme\DemoBundle\Repository\ArticleRepository" entity repository
>   implements
>   "Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepositoryInterface",
>   but its service could not be found. Make sure the service exists and
>   is tagged with "doctrine.repository_service".

If i remove the repositoryClass from the entity definition, I dont have the error anymore and i can use doctrine as such from my controller:

```
this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Article::class)->findBy([], null, $limit, ($page - 1) * $limit);
```

I tried adding the repository as a service in the bundle service definition but it does not change anything:

## vendor/Acme/demo-bundle/Resources/config/services.yaml

```
services:
  Acme\DemoBundle\Repository\:
    resource: '../../Repository/ArticleRepository.php'
    autoconfigure: true
    tags: ['doctrine.repository_service']
```

bin/console debug:autowire or debug:container wont show the service.

I also tried adding the extension:

```
namespace Acme\BlogBundle\DependencyInjection;


use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Extension\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader;

class AcmeBlogExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $loader = new YamlFileLoader(
            $container,
            new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config')
        );
        $loader->load('services.xml');
    }
}
```

Did not work either. I dont have the impression that the extension is being called. I tried adding a constructor to it and dump, die in the constructor, but there are no results of the dump.

So my question is how do i define my repositories as a service from the vendor directory ?

The source code is overhere: https://github.com/khalid-s/sf4-bundle-test

Comment: Your bundle needs an extension in DI namespace to load its configuration files. In your test example it means creating a class like `Acme\BlogBundle\DependencyInjection\BlogExtension`.

Comment: @Heah I updated my extension accordingly but still it would not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much struggling, i succedded in my task. I dont think that's it should be done like this, but if this can help someone...

I added in my DependencyInjection folder of the bundle:

```
class AcmeBlogExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $loader = new YamlFileLoader(
            $container,
            new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config')
        );
        $loader->load('services.yaml');
    }
}
```

I created a compiler (this is the part which i struggled to figure out) to register my service

```
class RepositoryCompiler implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $container->register('acme_blog.repository', ArticleRepository::class);
    }
}
```

I added in my Bundle class:

```
class AcmeBlogBundle extends Bundle
{
    /** @info this function normally is useless */
    public function getContainerExtension()
    {
        // This is only useful if the naming convention is not used
        return new AcmeBlogExtension();
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $container->addCompilerPass(new RepositoryCompiler());

        parent::build($container);
    }
}
```

And finally the service itself:

```
services:
  Acme\BlogBundle\Repository\:
    resource: '../../Repository/*Repository.php'
    autoconfigure: true
    autowire: true
    tags: ['doctrine.repository_service']
```

The autoconfigure and autowire are useless since they are not taken into consideration when i debug:container which looks like this:

```
php bin/console debug:container acme

Information for Service "acme_blog.article.repository"
=======================================================

 ---------------- -----------------------------------------------
  Option           Value
 ---------------- -----------------------------------------------
  Service ID       acme_blog.article.repository
  Class            Acme\BlogBundle\Repository\ArticleRepository
  Tags             doctrine.repository_service
  Public           yes
  Synthetic        no
  Lazy             no
  Shared           yes
  Abstract         no
  Autowired        no
  Autoconfigured   no
 ---------------- -----------------------------------------------
```

**One very important note which made me loose a lot of time:**

> Do clear your cache after every change to your services. Even in dev
>   mode they are not reloaded after every refresh